# Having trouble with return values for user-defined Functions

Tags: c++, function, return

I'm doing a simple Pythagorean function
User inputs two numbers, both numbers are shipped off to a user-defined function called Hypo, and hypo's supposed to return one value, C, which is the answer.

Here's my script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int hypo(double a, double b);

int main(void)
{ 
   double one, two;
   //user inputs two variables
   scanf("%lf %lf", &one, &two );
   printf("Your C number is: %.2lf\n", hypo(one, two));

   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int hypo(double a, double b)
{
    double c;
    c = sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
    printf("Currently, A = %.2lf, and B = %.2lf, C = %.2lf\n", a, b, c);

    return c;
}
```

On my computer, it works all the way until the end, Return c; which for some reason, returns the value 0 to the Main function. (I tested to see just where the error was, hence the printscreening in the hypo function.)

I want to understand this.

I'm pretty sure I have the synax wrong, or there's something I didn't read yet that's gone over my head, but after an hour of looking through books and checking youtube videos, I don't understand why this isn't working.

EDIT:

Thank you all for the fast replies! I changed it to a double, (realizing my mistake in the process too xD ) and it works like a charm now. 
Very happy with how fast you guys all answered, I'll be sure to pass it forward :)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Of course it compiles. `double` to `int` is a standard conversion, and C-style variadic functions provide no type checking whatsoever. The biggest problem here is the use of `scanf` and `printf` rather than the type-safe C++ equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the return type to double:

```
double hypo(double a, double b)
{
    double c;
    c = sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
    printf("Currently, A = %.2lf, and B = %.2lf, C = %.2lf\n", a, b, c);

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your return type is `int` when you probably want `double` - small values will be casted and result in 0 (i.e. 0.5 is 0 when stored in `int`).

The exact reason why you are getting 0 is mismatched formatting - you use float formatting to print integer value. For printing integer use `%d`, but if you specify return type of `hypo` correctly (`double`) this problem will disappear.

Comment: The wrong result is because of the format string mismatch (int vs double), not a result of rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You have `hypo` returning an `int`, but you're using it as if it's a `double`.  You should switch it to:

```
double hypo(double a, double b);
```

And, in the implementation:

```
double hypo(double a, double b)
{
    double c;
    // ...
```

When you return as an `int`, the resulting value `c` will get truncated to an `int` instead of displaying the full value.  This will cause it to convert to 0 for anything positive number less than 1.0.  Also, your format string is specifying a double, and you're passing an int, which will cause the display to always print the wrong answer.

Comment: The wrong result is because of the format string mismatch (int vs double), not a result of rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your variable `c` as type double:

```
double c;
```

But you are trying to return an `int`:

```
int hypo(double a, double b);
```

You should either change the return type of `hypo` to `double` or cast `c` to `int`. However, casting will throw away any fractions (making 2.678 into 2):

```
return (int)c;
```

Therefore I recommend you change the return type to `double` instead, which is also more logical when trying to calculate the hypotenuse (which may contain fractional digits):

```
double hypo(double a, double b);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining all that, it was an "Doh!" error when I read your solutions, but the details and explanation will really make sure I won't get this wrong again! :)